# (Very) hard to find Highcharts error

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Highcharts doesn't really do error reporting, as some of you have probably found out. So far, I learned that the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` often means you neglected to add a `renderTo` element in the chart config. Now I need to figure out this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I am dynamically generating my config object, but this is what it looks like (in JSON format):

```
{
    "chart": {
        "renderTo": "someId",
        "type": "line"
    },
    "xAxis": {},
    "yAxis": {
        "title": {}
    },
    "series": [
        {
            "name": "a",
            "data": [
                1,
                2
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "b",
            "data": [
                1,
                3
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "c",
            "data": [
                2,
                4
            ]
        }
    ],
    "credits": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "tooltip": {}
}
```

Can anyone help me see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I actually figured it out. The problem comes from the fact that I'm using Highcharts in an unconventional way. In a javascript class constructor, I was doing something like this:

```
function MyGraph(options) {
  // Manipulate options, generate my own defaults
  Highcharts.Chart.call(this, options);
}
```

Highcharts no likey, so I just did this instead:

```
function MyGraph(options) {
  // Manipulate options, generate my own defaults
  $.extend(this, Highcharts.Chart(options));
}
```